# Changing the direction in which an ul expands when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I got a button which when clicked, toggles the visibility of an ul. My button element is a child of my footer, which is fixed to the bottom of my screen. The issue I am having is that when toggled, the ul expands downward instead of up. How would I go about making my ul expand upwards with the first li item starting from the bottom, with each succeeding li item stacking on top of the one before it.

Here is my code:

```
<footer class="web-stream">

    <button type="button" class="active-stream">All</button>

    <ul class="feed-list">
       <li>feed 1</li>
       <li>feed 2</li>
    </ul>

</footer>
```

CSS

```
.web-stream {
background: green; 
width: 100%
height: 2.3em; 

margin: auto;

position: fixed;
bottom:0%;
left:0px;
right:0px;
}

.active-stream {
width: 9.5em;
height: 2.3em;
text-align: center;
}

.feed-list {
display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','.active-stream', function(event) {        
        jQuery('.feed-list').toggle('fast');   //use 'slow'
        });
 });
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FDMg6/).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "expand upwards" and the `li`s stacking _on top_ of each other. What I see happening is the bottom div grows upwards and your `ul` slides in from the left.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4574501/jquery-vertical-up-toggle-i-e-not-down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question properly, you just need to reverse the order of the list. If the content is dynamically generated then you could do this when you output the `<li>` tags.  Otherwise the JS in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y54Hb/) can accomplish the same thing.

I also moved the button to appear below the list to match your drawing.

Comment: Why the downvote? The results of my JSFiddle match the image the asker supplied and I explained my solution and a potentially better one.